# Setting up a path for Haskell-Linter in VS Code on windows 10

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, linter

I am trying to make haskell-linter to work on VS Code on my windows 10 machine. Apparently you need to add a path to the .exe file for it to work. I get this error message.
[Cannot hlint the haskell file. The hlint program was not found. Use the 'haskell.hlint.executablePath' setting to configure the location of 'hlint'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw1oE.png)
In the Dependencies options there is following information.

> It expects a version of hlint >= 1.9.1 to be installed and already added to >the path. If it is installed but cannot be found, add the path to your >preferences as seen below"
>
> "haskell.hlint.executablePath": "Path\To\Executable"

I tried adding a path in the system environment as such.

Variablename: `haskell.hlint.executablePath`

Variablevalue: `C:\Users\name\.vscode\extensions\hoovercj.haskell-linter-0.0.6\node_modules\.bin`

I am fairly sure the variable value is the thing wrong here. I think I need to find the path to the .exe file for for the extension, but I can't seem to find it in the folder containing the extension itself. There is probable an easy fix that I am just to inexperienced to see. Please help, and if you do, explain it as if I was 8. :)

Edit 1: I now know where to put the path to what i assume must be the .exe file for Haskell-linter, however i don't know where that file is. As stated i cant find any .exe files in the extension folder.

Edit 2: I reinstalled hlint and added the new path. it finally seems to work as intended.

Comment: vscode is _not_ asking for a system variable . it is asking for a preference value by that key in the settings.json file. read more e.g. here: https://supunkavinda.blog/vscode-editing-settings-json

Comment: Thank you LudvigH, i now have the file where the path goes open in my textedditor, however it still leaves the problem of finding the path to the .exe file for said extension right? or am i missing something?

Comment: you need to install `hlint` manually, and in that installation process, you would produce the `.exe` file in question. did you do that?

Comment: I have now tried installing a new version of hlint and manually set up a path to it using the "where hlint" command in terminal to find the path. It seems to finally work now. Thank you for your help LudvigH!